# SSH in xampp install php

Tags: php, ssh, xampp, libssh2

I need to use a connection SSH and PHP, I have version PHP 5.6.8 ,

```
intall  OpenSSL-Win32;
In php.ini :
extension=libssh2.dll   ;librerias ssl2
extension=php_ssh2.dll 
The libraries are in the folder php---->ext.

With the next program my result is:
Fatal error: Call to undefined function ssh2_connect() in            
    C:\xampp\htdocs\conexion\conexion_ssh.php on line 2

        <?php
        $connection = ssh2_connect('X.X.X.X', XX);

        if (ssh2_auth_password($connection, 'root', 'XXXXXXXX')) {
          echo "Authentication Successful!\n";
        } else {

          die('Authentication Failed...');
        }

        ?>
```

Do you know the problem? I think is the configuration the system variable PATH but I don't Know the process.

Thanks for you help me!

Comment: Is `php_ssh2` listed in "Loaded Modules" of [`phpinfo()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.phpinfo.php)? Do you have any error in the PHP error log (as set by `error_log` directive)?

Comment: You could use phpseclib as a workaround. It has a number of advantages over libssh2 as elaborated at http://phpseclib.sourceforge.net/ssh/compare.html